# Unable to identify the behavior of Python virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to create a virtual environment to install scrapy. I installed it using the command:

`virtualenv --no-site-packages [name]`

I then created a virtual environment and checked `pip freeze`. It showed me the basic packages. I activated the virtual environment and installed scrapy, using:

`pip install scrapy`

The packages were also accessed outside the venv, and I can see the scrapy in `/usr/bin` using:

`which scrapy`

I am unable to identify the behavior, can anybody please explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, it sounds to me like you are wondering why you can access `scrapy` when the virtual environment is deactivated.

Make sure that `scrapy` is not installed globally by running this command when the virtual environment is deactivated:

```
pip uninstall scrapy
```

Then retry your steps to install `scrapy` within the virtual environment:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install scrapy
which scrapy
  >> venv/bin/scrapy
deactivatte
which scrapy
  >> scrapy not found
```

Hope I helped.